# How do I change mail port for mail() on my local machine?

Tags: php, email

Xfinity comcast router/service blocks my mail port 25.

I forwarded port 42000 instead
in my `/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini` file I changed the `smtp_port` as well

```
; http://php.net/smtp
smtp_port = 42000
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

The `php tail -f /var/log/mail.log` is still giving me this error though

> postfix/smtp[20061]: connect to
>   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.21.23]:25: Operation timed out

Comment: Investigate PHPMailer/SwiftMailer instead of `mail()`.

Comment: Gmail uses `465` / `587` ports http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: The server doesn't care what ports you've forwarded.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams This is a server on my local machine